# Show that a series function is continuous in $\Bbb R$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions, continuity

I've been trying to solve this following question:

> Prove that $f(x)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\arctan(\frac{2x}{x^2+n^3})$ is continuous in $\Bbb R$.

I would really appreciate if someone can give me some direction on how to approach this problem.

Comment: Hint: uniform convergence.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the arc function, with the same function without arctan, and just deal with a series $(2x/(x^2+n^3))$ since this series is always bigger, you prove that this series is bigger and by the supremum's rule you can prove that the arc uniformly converges.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).